# SFML cannot open source file in a project pulled from github

Tags: github, sfml

I have an sfml project that I pushed onto my github account.
Using a different computer, I cloned the repository. I went into project property and made sure that the additional include and lib all points to the right location. All the project setup should be done right(and I know for sure because I did it once and finished my project with it).

But now my project is saying "cannot open source file "SFML\Graphics.hpp".
The most common issue is that the include/lib are not configured correctly, but that is absolutely not the case here. Perhaps it's not working because I pulled it from git, unlike before where I would configure my additional include/lib first then start working on my project. I've ran into this issue several times but still struggles to find a fix. Other than telling me to be 200% sure that my additional include/lib are right, any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is SFML set up correctly on the computer?
Are the environment variables using the same name for SFML?

Double check that SFML is installed and configured properly and that the environment variable for SFML is correct and pointing to the right location.
You may have to restart your computer for VS to recognize the new environment variables.